# How do I check if a Cache element has expired in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, memcached, laravel-5.1

I want to store an array in Cache. I'm using "MemCached" as Cache driver and it works like a charm in queries, but I want to use it for my search suggestions. I've been looking at Laravel Documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache) but I haven't been able to find what I were looking for.

For example, I have this function in which if I find the element on Cache I get it. If not, I get results from DB and then store them on Cache for 10 minutes:

```
public function get_suggestions() {

      if(Cache::get('search_suggestions')) {
        return $search_suggestions;
      } else {
        $search_suggestions = Suggestions::get();
        Cache::put('search_suggestions', '$search_suggestions', 10);
        return $search_suggestions;          
}

}
```

Some questions:

1. If the element in Cache expires, what will the Cache::get function returns?
2. There is a function to check if the element exists in the database but is there anyone to check if the Cache item has expires?
3. Is my approach OK to manage the Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Cache::has` to check for existance.

But in your case I suggest to use `Cache::remember`

```
public function get_suggestions() {
    return Cache::remember('search_suggestions', 10, function() {
        return Suggestions::get();
    });
}
```

Comment: But... all elements that are expired are removed from the cache? Or can be elements that are on the cache althoug they have expire already?

Comment: If a cache items expires, it will be deleted. If you want a different behavior, you have to write an own cache handler

Comment: No, that's the behaviour I expect. Thanks!